# Can I include the constant of integration when I perform a derivative?

Tags: integration, derivatives

Let's say I have$$x=-\alpha t^2$$
Is it fair to say that$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-(2\alpha t+c)\tag 1$$
Where $c$ is the constant of integration. The reason I ask is, if we take one more derivative:$$\frac{dx^2}{d^2t}=-2\alpha$$and then take the anti-derivative, we get:
$$\int -2\alpha\space dt=\frac{dx}{dt}=-(2\alpha t+c)\tag 2$$Do I have to calculate that the second derivative is $2\alpha$ before I can take the antiderivative and introduce the integration constant into the relation or can I stop after Eq (1) above? It seems to me that $\frac{dx}{dt}$ should always equal $\frac{dx}{dt}$. Am I missing something?

Comment: For line $(1)$, no. Consider the slope of the first equation at each $t$, there is only one value and adding a non-zero constant $c$ would be wrong.

Comment: Then what am I missing? If I go through the extra steps of taking the second derivative, and then taking the anti-derivative, I get back to $\frac{dx}{dt}$, how is this version of $\frac{dx}{dt}$ different from Eq (1)?

Comment: @Quarkly antiderivative of a derivative is not necessarilly the original function because antiderivative operator has a multivalued nature.

Comment: From $x$, differentiating once you get a unique $\frac{dx}{dt}$, differentiating again you get a unique $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -2\alpha$. But the antiderivative is not unique, there are infinite of them all differ by a constant, and only one of them is your original first derivative (when $c=0$ in your case):

$$\int -2\alpha\ dt = \frac{dx}{dt}+c = -(2\alpha t + c_1)$$

Comment: @peterwhy - Alright. I think what you're saying makes sense. If this described a manifold, which of the two methods describes the tangent velocity, taking the simple derivative in Eq (1), or integrating the second derivative in Eq (2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a function $x=x(t)$ then $\frac{dx}{dt}$ represents the gradient of that function. This can only be represented as a single value. If this constant was here that would imply $x(t)$ has multiple gradients at a given point $t$, which breaks our definition of it being a function (1:1 map). You are correct in that if we know $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ and integrate to find $\frac{dx}{dt}$ we will have a constant of integration, but this constant comes from the fact that we do not know the exact function but rather a family of functions, which can be singled down to one function through boundary or initial conditions. For example:

If I know that:
$$v(t)=2t$$
then we can say that:
$$s(t)=\int v(t)\,dt=\int 2t\,dt=t^2+C$$
now this constant is here since we know the family of functions $s$ belongs to but we do not know the exact solution. In this context imagine $v$ as velocity and $s$ as displacement. From the velocity we can determine the form of $s$ but we cannot specify this constant unless we know the value of $s$ at some point, for example the initial displacement. If I said that $s(0)=0$ then it is clear that $C=0$.

This is a nice real world way of visualising why we have integration constants when integrating but not differentiating

---

In addition if we work backwards from the assumption that:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-(2\alpha t+c)$$
we get:
$$x(t)=-\alpha t^2-ct+d$$
where $d$ is another integration constant. You can see that this function cannot match our known form of $x(t)$ unless $c$ (and actually $d$) is equal to $0$

Answer (score 1):

It's not fair to say (using your example) that
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=-(2\alpha t+c)
$$
The constant of integration comes from unbounded integrals actually giving us a family of functions, not a single function.

You are correct that the integral of the second derivative is the first derivative. However, this integral is unbounded meaning we get every function that when differentiated gives the integrand. $-2\alpha t$ is just one of those functions (when $c=0$). By knowing the function $x$, you have placed a condition upon your integral allowing you to calculate $c$. However if you had not been given $x$, then you'd be correct in you assertion in (1).

> As a side note (only loosely related), in more complex integration it can sometimes be useful to give a non-zero value to $c$ when to give us some useful cancelation inside the integral

Comment: Same question as above: If this described a manifold, which of the two methods describes the tangent velocity, taking the simple derivative in Eq (1), or integrating the second derivative in Eq (2)?